# Jenkins pipeline for building other jobs

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have four iOS frameworks that I build in Jenkins.  The jobs are sdk_ios_f1, sdk_ios_f2, sdk_ios_f3, and sdk_ios_f4.  There is an xcode project that uses these frameworks.  It is sdk_ios_p.

I want to create a Jenkins pipeline that will build these jobs in order:

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage('Desc1') {
        steps {
            dir('/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/') {
                build job: 'sdk_iOS_f1', quietPeriod: 5
                build job: 'sdk_iOS_f2', quietPeriod: 5
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Desc2') {
        steps {
            dir('/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/') {
                build job: 'sdk_iOS_d3', quietPeriod: 5
                build job: 'sdk_iOS_f4', quietPeriod: 5
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The two stages are shown on the Jenkins page and the pipeline starts but it never gets past scheduling the first build (sdk_ios_f1).

Please, what do I need to do in order to run the jobs and in the order listed?

```
Started by user Smith Smith
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/pipeline_all_develops
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Desc1)
[Pipeline] dir
Running in /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] build (Building sdk_iOS_f1)
Scheduling project: sdk_iOS_f1
```

(never gets past here)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! Haha.  There was only one executor so the pipeline was blocking all others.  I added an executor and all is well.