# Looking for a jenkins pipeline build job syntax that really works

Tags: jenkins, build, parameters, jenkins-pipeline, jobs

I'm trying to trigger a jenkins pipeline job from inside another jenkins pipeline job, with parameters.
I'm relatively newbie in java/groovy so I search the web for functional samples but all that I found are unusable for syntax or scripting reasons.
Some of my tests below:

[How to trigger another Jenkins pipeline that needs a $BRANCH variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58703438/how-to-trigger-another-jenkins-pipeline-that-needs-a-branch-variable)

```
node() {
    build job: 'INVENTORIES', propagate: true, wait: true
}
Failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'build' found among steps [ansiblePlaybook
```

[Jenkins pipeline for building other jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50727318/jenkins-pipeline-for-building-other-jobs)

```
node() {
    stage('Desc1') {
        steps {
            dir('/var/lib/jenkins/workspace') {
                build job: 'INVENTORIES', propagate: true, wait: true
            }
        }
    }
}
Failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'steps' found among steps [ansiblePlaybook,

node() {
    stages {
        stage ("build") {       //an arbitrary stage name
            steps {
                build 'INVENTORIES' //this is where we specify which job to invoke.
            }
        }
    }
}
Failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'stages' found among steps [ansiblePlaybook,
```

I've tried plenty of samples (script block, step block, stage block...) but it never works, always throwing java exception like:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep.delegate expects interface jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep but received class ...
```

Before I jump from a bridge, could anyone here helps me?
Thanks in advance, I know swimming but it's a little cold

Comment: This should work: `node() { build job: 'INVENTORIES', propagate: true, wait: true }`. Have you installed the pipeline plugin?

Comment: @Zett42: Thanks for reply. I'm afraid it is not the good script either: `code` java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'build' found among steps [ansiblePlaybook, ansibleVault, archive, bat, catchError, checkout, deleteDir, dir, echo, emailext, emailextrecipients, error, fileExists, getContext, git, isUnix, junit, load, mail, node, .... at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:202)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122) `code`

Comment: The above works for me. There is propably an issue with your Jenkins installation. Maybe you need to update, maybe plugins are missing or messed up. Try to do a clean installation of the latest version.

Comment: I had a look at what plugins I've loaded and realize that some were missing. It seems to solve the problem but know I'm facing ssl problems that I had solved before adding the plugins. So thanks for your suggest.

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED]
It were missing a Pipeline Plugin but the error messages wasn't clear enought and log content too poor to guess.
Thanks to @zett42 to have pointed me on the good search way.
Have a nice day.